# How to use assets from an imported Angular library?

Tags: angular

I created an Angular 9 library and a demo app with CLI.

```
ng new i18-workspace --create-application=false
ng g library i18n-lib
ng g application demo-i18n
```

The goal is to have the library export some i18n, which should be read by the application, using `ngx-translate`. This way, when the application uses a component from the library, it should be internationalized.
So I created some i18n files in my library, and modified `ng-package.json` according to the [doc](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md):

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets/**/*.json"
]
```

This works fine and when I build the library, I can see the i18n files under `dist/i18n-lib/src/assets/i18n/`.
Now I struggle to use these files in my demo-app:
If I try to use the previous path in my loader, I have a 404:`Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/dist/i18n-lib/src/assets/i18n/lib-fr.json: 404 Not Found`. I think this is because these files are not part of my demo application assets.
So I tried to include them into the application assets by adding a line to the `angular.json`:

```
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*.json",
    "input": "projects/dist/i18n-lib/src/assets",
    "output": "projects/demo-i18n/assets"
  },
  "projects/demo-i18n/src/favicon.ico",
  "projects/demo-i18n/src/assets"
]
```

But this is not doing anything... Any help, clue appreciated !